# orderByRaw remove part of the query in Laravel 4.2

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm working on an advanced search engine on an announcement website. I must use `orderByRaw` at some point because I need to order in a complicated way. The problem is it literally removes part of the SQL and I don't know how to solve this.

The query using the chaining

```
  $announcements = Announcement::select('announcements.*')
                               ->getOnline()
                               ->withCitySlug($location)
                               ->withCategory($category_id)
                               ->orderByResearchPageOption()
                               ->get();
```

Here's the interesting part of the model `Announcement` itself

```
  public function scopeOrderByResearchPageOption() {

    return $this->leftJoin('announcement_options', 'announcements.id', '=', 'announcement_options.announcement_id')
                ->orderByRaw('CASE
                              WHEN announcement_options.option_slug = "research_page" then 1 
                              WHEN announcement_options.option_slug = "" then 2 
                              ELSE 3 END')
                ->select('announcements.*'); // to avoid leftJoin bullshit

  }

  public function scopeGetOnline($query) {

    return $query->where('status', '=', 'online');

  }

  public function scopeWithCitySlug($query, $city_slug) {

    if (empty($city_slug)) return $query;

    return $query->where('city_slug', 'LIKE', '%'.$city_slug.'%');

  }

  public function scopeWithCategory($query, $category_id) {

    if ($category_id === FALSE) return $query;

    return $query->join('announcement_categories', 'announcement_categories.announcement_id', '=', 'announcements.id')
                 ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'announcement_categories.category_id')
                 ->where('categories.id', '=', $category_id);

  }
```

When I remove `orderByResearchPageOption()` for the query, the raw SQL is

```
  array(3) { ["query"]=> string(284) "select `announcements`.* from `announcements` inner join `announcement_categories` on `announcement_categories`.`announcement_id` = `announcements`.`id` inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `announcement_categories`.`category_id` where `status` = ? and `categories`.`id` = ?" ["bindings"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "online" [1]=> int(11) } ["time"]=> float(1.88) }
```

And it works perfectly as wanted, but when I add it, it changes the whole query, and we lose the binding logic, etc.

```
 array(3) { ["query"]=> string(375) "select `announcements`.* from `announcements` left join `announcement_options` on `announcements`.`id` = `announcement_options`.`announcement_id` order by CASE WHEN announcement_options.option_slug = "research_page" then 1 WHEN announcement_options.option_slug = "" then 2 ELSE 3 END" ["bindings"]=> array(0) { } ["time"]=> float(16.12) }
```

Does someone have an idea what to do here ? I'm truly lost, I can't avoid this `orderByRaw` for the project, i searched a lot for it ...

Another idea would be to convert everything in raw SQL but it's really not flexible and i prefer this way :(

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid error at the end, for anyone who would get a similar problem, just don't forget to replace `$this` by the current `

```
public function scopeOrderByResearchPageOption($query) {

    return $query->leftJoin('announcement_options', 'announcements.id', '=', 'announcement_options.announcement_id')
                ->orderByRaw('CASE
                              WHEN announcement_options.option_slug = "research_page" then 1 
                              WHEN announcement_options.option_slug = "" then 2 
                              ELSE 3 END')
                ->select('announcements.*'); // to avoid leftJoin bullshit

  }
```